# Javascript get the first picture as a thumbnail for the blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function to get the first image in my post as thumbnail for Blogger. This code has 2 parts. It gets the first image in the post otherwise it will get the image in the first `img` tag.

It is working well, but I want to fix it to always get the image in the first `img` tag.

```js
function A(t, e) {
  var a = t[e].title.$t,
    s = t[e].content.$t,
    v = $("<div>").html(s);
  if ("media$thumbnail" in t[e]) {
    var i = t[e].media$thumbnail.url,
      l = i.replace("/s72-c", "/w860"),
      o = i.replace("/s72-c", "/w860");
    i.match("img.youtube.com") && (l = i.replace("/default.", "/mqdefault."), o = i)
  } else o = -1 < s.indexOf("<img") ? l = v.find("img:first").attr("src").replace("/d", "/w860") : (l = noThumbnail.replace("/s680", "/w280"), noThumbnail.replace("/s680", "/w120"));
  return ['<div class="post-thumb" style="background-image:url(' + l + ')"/>', '<div class="post-thumb" style="background-image:url(' + o + ')"/>']
}
```

Comment: Is this code minified?

Comment: I made you a snippet. PLEASE replace the minified code with actual code in a [mcve]